# Creating a Custom Setup in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, windows-installer

I am new to visual Studio 2013. I want to create a custom setup(REPACK) for installing Games.
I created a setup using Visual Studio Setup Project but the UI and design was ugly i want to alter the design and descriptions.

I just need a Nice looking Game Installer.
For example(just like Blackbox,Skidrow or RG Mechanics)

Can anyone tell me how to do it ?

Any good tutorial for want i want will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Setup Projects are the bare basics of installer projects and while there is some room for customization here and there it'll never be pretty.

Windows Installer XML (WIX) is a very flexible system that generates installation packages for windows applications and leverages the standard MSI system built into Windows. WIX has a very steep learning curve (being XML and all), but is extremely flexible. The installer of the WIX Toolkit, which of course was written in WIX and C#, already shows some of the possibilities. The visual Studio 2012 and 2013 installers were also built on top of WIX.

A tutorial can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/583223/Customizing-the-WIX-Installer
The WIX toolset for Visual Studio can be downloaded here: http://wixtoolset.org/